# What happens if Shen teleports to Nocturne when Nocturne is in midflight using his ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

Will Nocturne appear at the spot Nocturne is at the moment, or will he be at the start or the end?

How is nocturne moving when using ulti? Is he a projectile or just getting a gazillion MS?

Comment: Please refer to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/63235/20893

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of Shen teleporting to Nocturne during Nocturne's ultimate.

Shen appears wherever Nocturne was when his ultimate is done channeling. In the video it makes Shen appear in the dragon pit when Nocturne's target was in the river.

Answer (score 1):

He will appear at the spot nocturne  is at the moment if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

If the Shen starts channeling his Ult at the same time that Nocturne Ults (and Nocturne doesn't immediately die, or Shens' Channel isn't interrupted) Shen will appear at the end of the channel at whatever point on the map the Nocturne was at when it finished.

For instance, if Nocturne at Lv 18 Ulted a Fiddlesticks at the very edge of his Ult range at the exact same time a Shen ulted HIM, the Shen would appear either right next to Nocturne as he collided, or 700ish range behind him. Alternatively, if the Shen used the Portraits on the left-hand side of the screen to target the Nocturne mid-Ult, then he would appear exactly where the Nocturne is at the end of the Ult, as Nocturne would already have stopped moving so quickly.

As for your second question, Nocturne is technically doing a dash (similar to Graves, Ahri, Tristana, Akali, and several other champions), and is neither a projectile or getting a severe MSpd boost. He IS killable during his dash, just like all the other champions, AND Darius' Apprehend works on and cancels it out (if this has not been hotfixed in a recent patch, that is).