# While traveling during his ultimate, is Nocturne targetable by friends or foes?

Tags: league-of-legends

After Nocturne uses Paranoia and subsequently launches himself at a target, can he be targeted by either friends or foes?

For instance, it's been shown that [Quicksilver Sash can remove the vision debuff](http://youtu.be/ihrfbmzAVPM). Could you remove the debuff and then stun him in-flight (removing the debuff so you could actually *see* him arriving)?

The answer for this should inform on what happens when a friendly [Shen ports to a mid-flight Nocturne](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/58477/19574). The fact Shen can even attempt to port a mid-flight Nocturne leads me to believe he's more-or-less targetable, but I haven't seen any definitive evidence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nocturne is [immune to Crowd Control effects when he jumps](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nocturne_the_Eternal_Nightmare/Ability_Details). When the enemy tries to CC Nocturne in-flight (even without targeting him, such as using Janna's Howling Gale), the message "Cannot Be Disabled" will appear above him.

Shen can teleport to an in-flight Nocturne because Shen's shield and ult are not CC.

**EDIT**: Michel found this [great Youtube clip](http://youtube.com/watch?v=_8VlyFgbnGw&t=1m18s) that shows this in action.

<del>Conceivably, Nocturne could be targeted by an auto-attack in-flight. But since the enemy team usually doesn't have any vision and he moves quickly out of auto-attack range even if there is vision, this rarely happens.</del>

If you watch Nocturne's health in the Youtube clip carefully, you'll notice that even though he gets hit by Amumu's and Galio's ults, he doesn't take any damage. This *suggests* (doesn't prove) that he is immune to damage during his jump. It'd be great if somebody could test this and post the results.

Comment: Adding for your answer this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8VlyFgbnGw&t=1m18s

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys! If anyone has information about other conditional events (Caitlin's ultimate, for instance?), that would be awesome, but this I think answers the core of the question.

Comment: Amumu's ult was pretty late and missed. I wouldn't say he's immune to damage while jumping.